# Why are humans referred to as "flatheads" by Apocalypse in Age of Apocalypse?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, age-of-apocalypse

In Age of Apocalypse, Apocalypse refers over and over to humans as "flatheads". Is there a particular reason for doing so, besides being "insulting"?

I always thought that somehow not having the "x-genes" would make you "flat", but I don't recall any reference to say hey, humans are flatheads because their genes blabla...

Comment: As I recall, flatheads meant Neaderthal.

Comment: I always assumed it was a play on words of the term "flat scan" which referred to to people without powers.